# How to get Uniprot and swissprot cross references using Biopython

Tags: python, uniprot

I am struggling to use biopython to gather cross references such as GO annotation from Uniprot/swissprot text files ("`DR`" in the .txt files) using biopython.

From the [source code](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SwissProt-pysrc.html):

```
def _read_dr(record, value): 
    cols = value.rstrip(".").split('; ') 
    record.cross_references.append(tuple(cols))
```

This leads me to think that the following code should work, as this is how other features like annotation and features work.

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "swiss"):
    print(record.cross_references) #does not work, should return a list of DR rows
    print(record.features) #works, returns a list of parsed FT rows
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the attribute you should be looking for is `dbxrefs`:

```
[x for x in record.dbxrefs if x.startswith('GO:')]
```

Apparently `SeqIO` handles uniprot text files differently than the `SwissProt` module:

```
from Bio import SwissProt
record = SwissProt.read(open('single_record_from_uniprot.txt'))
record.cross_references
```

So you should change you code to use the `SwissProt` module to get the behavior you expect